# Laravel redirect to HTTPS with .htaccess

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

I'm using Laravel 5.5.

Laravel has couple of .htaccess and in my case I'm working with .htaccess on root and inside the public folder.

All this time I was using this code in root .htaccess to setup the public folder:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

and my website is loading when I enter the homepage.
After that, I wanted to force redirect all the pages using https. So, first when I try to put this code inside the root .htaccess it doesn't do anything. It keeps loading with http.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Well, it makes sense, because when I setup the public folder, I have to put the redirect inside the .htaccess that is located inside the public folder.

OK, so I've tried like this now:

The root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

The public .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This combination works. It does redirects to https.
But, there's one issue now. When I enter the homepage or if I open the website from the search results, the URL looks like this:

```
https://mywebsite.com/public/en
```

When I enter the other pages, I don't have issue related with the "public" path in the URL. So, let's say I want to open the contact page, the URL is https://mywebsite.com/en/contact. That's fine.

How can I avoid that "public" in my URL when I enter the homepage?

Comment: is there any reason why you are messing with the .htaccess file and not using nginx/apache to redirect the requests?

Comment: well, it's lot more easier using .htaccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should remove public from the url.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

I am not sure if  this should go above

```
# Handle Front Controller...
```

or within it? Maybe try either one and see if either work?

```
# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on    
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

[source](https://www.vimexx.nl/help/gratis-lets-encrypt-ssl-op-je-website-installeren)

Comment: This is not related to Laravel

Comment: @decagrog I also took the title into account